# issue in angluar with pipe(map)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, mean-stack

im trying to learn the mean stack and i have run in to an  issue with this code.

its giving this  error when compiling if you have an idea on how to solve this it would  be much appreciated

```
 getPosts() {
    this.http
      .get<{ message: string; posts:any }>(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/posts"
      )
      .pipe(map((postData) => {
        return postData.posts.map(post => {
          return {
            title: post.title,
            content: post.content,
            id: post._id
          };
        });
      }))
      .subscribe(transformedPosts => {
        this.posts = transformedPosts;
        this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
      });
  }
```

Error: src/app/posts/posts.service.ts:20:13 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'import("C:/Windows/System32/metric-server/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/types").OperatorFunction<{ message: string; posts: any; }, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("C:/Windows/System32/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/types").OperatorFunction<{ message: string; posts: any; }, any>'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
get<{ message: string; posts:any[] }>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!